# How to download data from un comtrade for all reporters and all partners (comtradr)

Tags: r

The task is to build a social network for trading certain goods. I have decided to use the un comtrade database. But this database has a limit on the number of countries to retrieve data. I need to get data about absolutely all countries. Who, how many and where imported. My code to download the data and the error I get when I try to download it:

```
codes <- ct_commodity_lookup("crude", return_code = T, return_char = T)

data <  ct_search(reporters = "All",partners = "All", trade_direction = "imports", start_date = "2020", end_date = "2020", commod_codes = codes[42])
```

Error:

```
Error: API request failed. Err msg from Comtrade:
  Both 'all' reporters and 'all' partners may not be selected. Select a different reporter or partner.
```

I understand this error, but for the task I need to get for all countries, and I don't really want to manually download for each of the five countries. Who has encountered this and how has this problem been solved?

Comment: Simply, loop through a vector/list of countries to build list of data frames (regularly asked `r` question on SO). Then `rbind` the list (regularly answered `r` solution on SO). Happy [researching](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and coding!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following can get you started. Loop through the countries names in English, taken from package `countrycode`, trap possible errors with `tryCatch` and after the loop separate the errors from the good.

```
library(comtradr)
library(countrycode)
library(jsonlite)

codes <- ct_commodity_lookup("crude", return_code = TRUE, return_char = TRUE)

data <- lapply(codelist$country.name.en[1:3], \(x) {
  Sys.sleep(1)
  tryCatch(
    ct_search(
      reporters = x, 
      partners = "All", 
      trade_direction = "imports", 
      start_date = "2020", 
      end_date = "2020", 
      commod_codes = codes[42]
    ),
    error = function(e) e
  )
})
names(data) <- codelist$country.name.en[1:3]
ok <- !sapply(data, inherits, "error")
err <- data[!ok]
data <- data[ok]
data
```